# Set Terminal tab name automatically?

Tags: terminal, big-sur, ssh

If I connect to one of my Pi using ssh
`ssh pi@MilliwaysPi4.local`

This sets the macOS terminal tab title to "pi@MilliwaysPi4"

If I connect to one of my Macs using ssh
`ssh ian@Zaphod.local`
The macOS terminal tab title remains at its default.

I can then manually set using the following:-
`echo -en "\033]1; $(hostname) \007"`

This sets the macOS terminal tab title to "Zaphod.local"

Is there any way to get macOS to automatically set the title?
Is there a ssh setting which would facilitate this behaviour?

---

I have tried many options;
Including `echo -en "\033]1; $(hostname) \007"` **after** `ssh` does not work, as any subsequent commands do not run on the host.

Including `echo -en "\033]1; $(hostname) \007"` **before** `ssh` sets the Title to the host on the host.

I could hard code the Title into a script before `ssh` which does work, but often I use IP Address rather than a HOSTNAME so this is not generic.

Apparently something happens when sshing to Linux which sets the title, but not when sshing to macOS. Ideally I would like to discover what this is.

---

The Linux .bashrc contains

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
```

although frankly this is inscrutable.

Comment: "... after ssh does not work, as any subsequent commands do not run on the host." doesn't make sense because the `echo` goes to Terminal so it doesn't matter on which host it runs. But check the shell init files on your Pi, whatever is done there to set the title will also work on your Mac.

Comment: @nohillside I tried, and it does nothing. The echo may work (but doesn't seem to). In any event the hostname needs to come from the target. `~/.bash_profile` contains `export PS1="\h:\[\033[0;30;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$ "` (which affects the prompt) but I am at a loss to find anything which would set title (but will continue looking)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem then: If you ssh into your Mac and run `echo -en "\033]1; $(hostname) \007"` once logged in, does the title change?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, this works . I wrote "I can manually set using the following:-
echo …" but maybe this is not clear to others. I will try putting into  ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: If it works manually it also works in bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the window title from the login script of your shell, by including the `echo` you run manually.